# InputStream.skip(long N) method throws Read timed out Exception

Tags: java, inputstream, ioexception, skip

There is a piece of code in orion server which uses InputStream.skip(long N) method.

When the request is submitted from client, Orion server calls this method and throws *Read timed out* Exception.

```
InputStream.skip(long N) method throws - Read timed out exception.
```

What could be the reason possibly?

Comment: From [here](https://coderanch.com/t/602741/java/java/Explain-java-net-SocketTimeoutException-Read): When getting a [java.net.SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) means the specific destination is unable to connect / unable to read. So I believe that in this case, if you're trying to `skip` over some bytes of data and your stream closes or disconnects, it should be handled.

Comment: Thank you @px06. But, If the straem closes or disconnects then this method will throw *Steam Closed* exception. The one I am facing is Read timed out.

Comment: The InputStream is probably "backed" by a socket, socket's you can specify a readTimeout.